# Parse string with coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have a string of data that I need to parse and populate in a structure similar to a form.

The data comes in a feed is as follows:

```
CHK_7F9CFAE8-155D-D714-405CFA5B0120F968=3&amp;CHK_7F9CFB3B-155D-D714-40F779AE41517787=3&amp;CHK_7F9CFBDC-155D-D714-40371A9ED516A4D3=3&amp;CHK_7F9CFBFC-155D-D714-40A4484DFB1C4825=3
```

I wish for the data to be structured as follows:

Struct

```
CHK_7F9CFAE8-155D-D714-405CFA5B0120F968   |   3
CHK_7F9CFB3B-155D-D714-40F779AE41517787   |   3
CHK_7F9CFBDC-155D-D714-40371A9ED516A4D3   |   3
CHK_7F9CFBFC-155D-D714-40A4484DFB1C4825   |   3

Fieldnames   |    CHK_7F9CFAE8-155D-D714-405CFA5B0120F968,CHK_7F9CFB3B-155D-D714-40F779AE41517787,CHK_7F9CFBDC-155D-D714-40371A9ED516A4D3,CHK_7F9CFBFC-155D-D714-40A4484DFB1C4825
```

Is there a way of doing this with coldfusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done .

```
    <cfset list1 = "CHK_7F9CFAE8-155D-D714-405CFA5B0120F968=3&amp;CHK_7F9CFB3B-155D-D714-40F779AE41517787=3&amp;CHK_7F9CFBDC-155D-D714-40371A9ED516A4D3=3&amp;CHK_7F9CFBFC-155D-D714-40A4484DFB1C4825=3">

<cfset list1 = "CHK_7F9CFAE8-155D-D714-405CFA5B0120F968=3&amp;CHK_7F9CFB3B-155D-D714-40F779AE41517787=3&amp;CHK_7F9CFBDC-155D-D714-40371A9ED516A4D3=3&amp;CHK_7F9CFBFC-155D-D714-40A4484DFB1C4825=3">

<cfset myStruct = structNew()>
<cfloop list="#list1#" delimiters="&amp;" index="i">
    <cfset 'mystruct.#replace(listGetAt(i,1,"="),'-','_','all')#'  = listGetAt(i,2,"=")>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#myStruct#">
```

Comment: slow to the party I guess.  I did it old school.  @imthepitts is the better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a go. **EDITED:** Accounting for multi-character delimeter.

```
    function structurize(required string data){
        var struct = {};
        var pairs = listToArray(replace(data, '&amp;', '&', 'all'), '&');
        for (var pair in pairs){
            struct[listFirst(pair, '=')] = listLast(pair, '=');
        } 
        struct.fieldnames = structKeyList(struct);
        return struct;
    }
    writeDump(structurize('CHK_7F9CFAE8-155D-D714-405CFA5B0120F968=3&amp;CHK_7F9CFB3B-155D-D714-40F779AE41517787=3&amp;CHK_7F9CFBDC-155D-D714-40371A9ED516A4D3=3&amp;CHK_7F9CFBFC-155D-D714-40A4484DFB1C4825=3'));
```

Comment: ListToArray will treat each of those five characters as individual delimiters. i.e. If the input contained lowercase hex it would break.

Comment: True, support for [multi-character delimiters](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f0f.html) was not added until CF10.

Comment: @PeterBoughton, the code above works on 9.0.2. What's this about lowercase hex?

Comment: It works _by coincidence_ - it does not delimit using the string `&amp;`. Run it against the data `chm_7f9cfae8-155d-d714-405cfa5b0120f968=pi&amp;etc` and you'll see what I'm saying.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterBoughton. I've updated my answer to swap `&amp;` for `&`. Glad to know this has been *accidentally* working, 'cause I'm sure I've done this elsewhere. :o)